# OpenVPN Setup and configuration

Tags: centos, openvpn

I have some questions about OpenVPN

1. What is the best GUI? I see there are many of them. Do I need that in order to connect to my server?
2. With the GUI am I able to select which VPN server I want to connect to if I run many?
3. What are the Authentication and Management GUI download for?

Reference: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RelatedProjects

Comment: You should define which OS you use...

Comment: CentOS is the current OS. Client would be Windows/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearos (which is based on centos) has a management gui for PPTP, IPSec and OpenVPN.

The easiest way I have found to set up OpenVPN in a gui is using PFSense 2 (which is my edge firewall).  It manages the whole set up of the different types of OpenVPN connections, certificates and gives you a great dynamic view into seeing who is connected when.  You could potentially run PFSense in a VM or even in a dedicated server.

OpenVPN also offers the Openvpn Access Server, which is a paid product that gives the additional certificate management and server GUI capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The "regular" Windows installer includes all the drivers and GUI necessary for client and server operations.  If you have multiple configurations, you can choose which profile to connect to.

I'm not familiar with #3.  I haven't used it in our environment.